# "Expect": + that-clause vs + to-infinitive

Tags: negation, infinitives, style-manuals, that

> In ‘*I **expect** J **will** come*’, you are simply saying you think
> he will, but in ‘*I **expect** J **to** come*’ you will be annoyed or
> disappointed if he does not.
>
> Instead of ‘**expect** something will **not**’ happen, you usually say
> *you do **not expect** it will* or *do not expect it to happen*.
>
> https://www.wordreference.com/EnglishUsage/expect

Does the distinction in the first paragraph apply to the negative sentences in the second, or only for ***expect** something **not** to happen* ?

Comment: No. The distinction in the first paragraph only happens in some contexts, with some speakers; it's hardly universal. There are many other ways to say things like this, and different people mean different things when they say them. This is language, not telepathy.

Answer (score -1):

Generally, yes.

"I expect J will not come" is a prediction

"I expect J not to come" indicates that the speaker will be annoyed of disappointed if J does come.

In British English the difference in meaning between the "that" clause and the infinitive is very clear for "expect".

For some other constructions the difference cannot be ascertained from the wording but is discerned by the emphasis when spoken. For example "He should be here" with an emphasis on the "here" means "I expect him to be here" but if the emphasis is on the "should" then it means "I expect that he is here".